# pmd or spotbugs rule to catch connection leaks?

Tags: java, pmd, spotbugs

Does anyone know the name of the PMD rule or Spot bugs detector which catches connection leaks  like one  here

```
try (PreparedStatement st_stage_CF = **Global.getConnection().**prepareStatement (" sql query "))
```

both pmd and spot bugs seem to miss it  even when I deliberately pit it in.
I'm trying to understand why oracle sometimes runs out of session very fast 1500 concurrent sessions in a space of 3 hours. The code above cause it in the past, so I'm wondering if it is the similar issue this time.
versions: Java 8, Oracle 10.2.0.5, Tomcat 7.0.92   PMD Plug-in  4.30.0.v20211127-1115-r , SpotBugs    3.1.13.201903011226-5013623   ,Eclipse Photon

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what's the problem with this connection? Is it because it's not closed?

Comment: @oowekyala  yes, it's not close when  written in this specific manner. The correct way is to write the following

Comment: try(Connection conn= Global. getConnection(); PreparedStatement st_stage_CF=conn.prepareStatement("sql query")) {//do stuff with query} Notiсе the variable conn that holds the connection . This allows the connection to be closed automatically by try with resources mechanism in Java

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my comment, I believe the PMD rule that should detect this is [CloseResource](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_errorprone.html#closeresource). If it doesn't detect it, please [file a bug report](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/new?assignees=&labels=a%3Afalse-negative&template=1rule_violation_false-negative.md&title=).